# Completely redesigning the front-end for the Drupal forum

Tags: javascript, html, drupal, drupal-7, forum

I only have web development experience with CakePHP, and I've recently started a Drupal project.  My main task is to re-skin the Drupal forums so instead of a normal comment chain, there is a timeline of icons connected by a tree structure that display a comment when you click on them.

This is a pretty radical overhaul, and while I'd feel confident about doing this in CakePHP, where I can just write HTML as I please, the structure of Drupal confuses me.  I've located the theme file that themes individual comments, but I'm not sure how to rewrite the page as a whole.  A forum topic appears to just be a node with comments, so I'm not completely sure how to re-theme the whole page.

To Summarize, I need to:

- Determine if any given node is a forum topic and replace the normal body with a scrollable timeline
- Display simple shapes representing posts taking place at a certain time on the timeline connected as a tree
- Hide the normal comments until the corresponding icons are clicked.
- Additionally, I need a way for the user to filter posts on the timeline by their tags, but once I figure out the Javascript for showing the posts, this shouldn't be terribly difficult.

Thanks for helping out a confused web dev.

Comment: As a start you can change template for any node type by following template naming convention. So clone original node.tpl.php change it's name to node--contentTypeName.tpl.php    clear the cache(!) and continue working on your new template, used only for your content type.

Comment: I didn't know about that.  I'd just been working in node.tpl.php and checking the type there.

Comment: That's not a good way to provide different template for different content type. Instead, make a new node template name it by following naming convention, clear the cache and start using it: https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656

Comment: This is nearly a year old now, but your comment should be an answer.  The link you posted, if I remember correctly, led me to the information I needed.